# Dynamically remove part of sql query upon execution

Tags: php, mysql

I am executing a mysql query. I am joining 4 tables. I want the two bold lines joined with the query only when p.location_id is not equal to 0. I want them to be simply not executed when p.location_id is equal to 0

```
SELECT p. * 
FROM property p, property_type pt, location l, city c
WHERE p.status =1
AND (
pt.prop_name LIKE  '%dlf%'
OR p.furnish LIKE  '%dlf%'
OR p.description LIKE  '%dlf%'
OR p.bed LIKE  '%dlf%'
OR p.term_condition LIKE  '%dlf%'
OR p.bedroom LIKE  '%dlf%'
OR p.property_type LIKE  '%dlf%'
OR c.city_name LIKE  '%dlf%'
**OR l.loct_name LIKE  '%dlf%'**
)
AND p.prop_id = pt.prop_id
AND p.city = c.city_id
**AND p.location_id = l.loct_id**
ORDER BY sortnum
```

Is there any way by which i can accomplish this.

Comment: You are looking for the IF statement of MySQL: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/if.html

Comment: Could you please guide me as to how the if condition can be executed in a sql query. I am not using a stored procedure

Comment: What do you mean by `stored procedure` ? Just read the manual of the IF-statement by the link I provided in my comment above.

Answer (score 0):

Keep the query in a string and concat the string as you want based on the conditions before execution....

The pseudo code would be

```
sql = "the query";

if(condition)
{
sql.="what you want to add"
}
```

Edit:
Try this
SELECT p. *.........IF(p.location_id != 0,AND p.location_id = l.loct_id,NULL) ORDER BY sortnum
Edit 2:

`SELECT p. * FROM property p, property_type pt, location l, city c WHERE p.status =1 AND (pt.prop_name LIKE '%dlf%' OR p.furnish LIKE  '%dlf%' OR p.description LIKE  '%dlf%' OR p.bed LIKE  '%dlf%' OR p.term_condition LIKE  '%dlf%' OR p.bedroom LIKE  '%dlf%' OR p.property_type LIKE  '%dlf%' OR p.property_type LIKE  '%dlf%' OR c.city_name LIKE  '%dlf%' OR (IF(p.location_id !=0 , l.loct_name LIKE  '%dlf%',NULL))) AND p.prop_id = pt.prop_id AND p.city = c.city_id AND (IF(p.location_id != 0),p.location_id = l.loct_id,NULL) ORDER BY shortnum`

Comment: The thing is tables are being joined. So i dont know beforehand for which which rows p.location_id=0. So this solution doesnt fit either

Comment: Could you please write the editted code in a syntactically correct way?

Comment: Try it : SELECT p. *.........AND p.city = c.city_id AND IF(p.location_id != 0, p.location_id = l.loct_id,NULL) ORDER BY sortnum

Comment: Try the edit 2 in the answer, this is the correct syntax,I have tested it, if you are getting any error,may be you are mistaking somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT p.* 
FROM property p, property_type pt, location l, city c
WHERE p.status =1
AND (
    pt.prop_name LIKE  '%dlf%'
    OR p.furnish LIKE  '%dlf%'
    OR p.description LIKE  '%dlf%'
    OR p.bed LIKE  '%dlf%'
    OR p.term_condition LIKE  '%dlf%'
    OR p.bedroom LIKE  '%dlf%'
    OR p.property_type LIKE  '%dlf%'
    OR c.city_name LIKE  '%dlf%'
    OR (p.location_id <> 0 AND l.loct_name LIKE  '%dlf%')
)
AND p.prop_id = pt.prop_id
AND p.city = c.city_id
AND (p.location_id = 0 OR p.location_id = l.loct_id)
ORDER BY sortnum
```

You just need a bit more of logical conditions. The code is still there but SQL won't run it when the condition you want happens.

Comment: This code doesnt work. "AND (p.location_id = 0 OR p.location_id = l.loct_id)" matches all rows with location id 0 even if there loc name isnt like dlf.